# how to execute delete statement inside plsql block and call it in a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written below pl sql block and trying to create a procedue. But i am getting warnings and not able to execute the procedue.

Please suggest if something i am missing \

**Please let me know if this question is duplicate as i am not able to get the exact link to refer**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EmployeeProc
IS 
BEGIN
delete from Employeetable where EmplId in (
select EmployeeId FROM EmployeeMstrTbl where JoiningDate between to_date('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2019-02-28','YYYY-MM-DD'));
commit;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted '||SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' records from Employeetable');
END;

Error: Object Invalid
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual error which is raised when you compile it.

Comment: @Tejash .. Thanks for the reply. I am getting error: "Procedure is invalid" and while creating procedure i am getting warning..

Comment: can issue `show error`, and tell us what you get .

Answer (score 1):

**Try using cursor**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMPLOYEEPROC IS 
CURSOR C1 IS 
SELECT EMPLOYEEID 
FROM EMPLOYEEMSTRTBL 
WHERE JOININGDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2019-02-28','YYYY-MM-DD'));
BEGIN
    FOR I IN C1 LOOP        
        DELETE FROM EMPLOYEETABLE 
        WHERE EMPLID=I.EMPLOYEEID;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETED '||SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' RECORDS FROM EMPLOYEETABLE');

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine.

```
CREATE TABLE Employeetable
(
    EmplId NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE EmployeeMstrTbl
(
    EmployeeId NUMBER,
    JoiningDate DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EmployeeProc
IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Employeetable
          WHERE EmplId IN
                    (SELECT EmployeeId
                       FROM EmployeeMstrTbl
                      WHERE JoiningDate BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2019-01-01',
                                                         'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                            AND TO_DATE ('2019-02-28',
                                                         'YYYY-MM-DD'));

    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        'Deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' records from Employeetable');
END;

EXEC EmployeeProc;

DROP TABLE Employeetable;
DROP TABLE EmployeeMstrTbl;
DROP PROCEDURE EmployeeProc;
```

Script output:

```
Table created.
Table created.
Procedure created.
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Table dropped.
Table dropped.
Procedure dropped.
```

DBMS Output:

```
Deleted 0 records from Employeetable
```

Maybe you have a typo in a table name, column name or something similar.

I suggest that you try to execute your delete statement first to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if perhaps you mistyped something, or if it is to do with how you have it set up. But even if it is a mistype and it could work, it's not nice, so do a loop.

```
i = 0;
FOR r in (select * FROM EmployeeMstrTbl where JoiningDate between to_date('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2019-02-28','YYYY-MM-DD'))
  LOOP
  DELETE FROM Employeetable where EmplId = r.EmployeeId;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted '|| i ||' records from Employeetable');
```

Because this will work, and more importantly, its easier to understand. Keeping code short and abbreviated has become much less important nowadays since the size of the code is almost never the problem, but keeping it easy to understand is extremely important so that it can be maintained in the future.

Comment: @TineO .. Thanks a lot for the reply.. But query is getting hang and its not able to delete the data

Comment: @Tejash yes, performance can be important when it comes to lots of data. But with the advancements in computer power, optimising for performance has become less important. If you know you are working on a large data set, then you might want to optimise for performance as you work, but trying to optimise all code for performance from the get go is a bad idea as it will most likely take longer and might be less readable. And the performance optimisation might not even make much of a difference.

Comment: @Ravi Then please try it out in the console as an unnamed procedure. First try the sql query for getting the IDs you want to delete, then use on of those in just a simple delete, if both those work try putting it all in the loop, then add whatever else you want in there. Run it down to the shortest reproducible example, find exactly where the problem arises, then come back to me and I will try and help.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree with this recommendation to switch to row by row deletes. That could cause tremendous performance issues if removing large numbers of rows. Use the set-oriented DELETE or use PL/SQL's FORALL statement to enable bulk processing of the DELETEs.

Comment: @StevenFeuerstein I yield, you know much better than I. I was simply going for the simple and well readable option. Bulk processing is indeed best with a FORALL, but I have never dealt with such quantities of data and am thus not experienced with it. But you certainly are, I learned a lot of what I know from your videos, so thank you.

Comment: @StevenFeuerstein.. Can you help me with any other best suggestionn please ?

Comment: @Ravi, not sure what you are asking for here.

Comment: @TimeO, for small volume of rows, sure FORALL is not necessary, but then neither would there be a concern about a single set-oriented delete. The bottom line is that Ravi doesn't really give us enough to properly diagnose and advise.

Comment: @StevenFeuerstein. As per my above question : is there any way i can update the data  much faster , can you help me with any suggestion

Comment: @Ravi you started with a report of errors. You are not getting any other errors now? As for updating much faster, I assume you mean deleting. Is there a problem now with performance? If so please verify that the query used in your IN clause is efficient (using indexes, etc.).